# Base class - should all methods be implemented

Tags: c#, inheritance

If I inherit from a base class, is there a rule which states "only inherit where you need to implement/use all (or X%) of the base classes functionality/methods"? I understand that if I inherit then I have inherited the lot, but that doesn't mean I have to use it all.

Assume the following pattern:

```
public abstract class Template
{   
    public void LoadCustomer()
    {
        //Load customer logic
    }
    public virtual void LoadGrid()
    {
        //Logic   
    }
    public virtual void other()
   { //logic }

    public virtual void other2()
   { //logic }

    public virtual void other3()
   { //logic }

    public string WelcomeMessage()
    {
         //perform lots of complex logic
         return "Hello and welcome";
    }
}
```

If part of my application wants to only show the WelcomeMessage(), would it be wrong to inherit from the Template class above (I know I can only inherit once but that isn't factor for this question) (also note, I've purposely not included any abstract methods/fields).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went down this road on quite a few of my projects before I "saw the light."

> is there a rule which states "only inherit where you need to implement/use all (or X%) of the base classes functionality/methods"?

Yes and no. No that there is no rule, but yes that there is a way to do what you want to do. It's call **favoring composition over inheritance** and what that means is that you need to break off each block of functionality into a single class, and then (in what is currently your sub-classes) create an instance of that class and then **delegate** the needed work to it. Using this technique will allow you to easily make modifications to what is currently your super-class without having ripple effects on your current sub-classes.

Bottom line, when in doubt (or if it just *feels* funny) don't use inheritance. This is embodied by the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which states that any sub-class should be a full and proper substitute for it's super class. (i.e. don't have `Boat` subclass `Plane` just because they can both carry people).

For more fun reading, check out the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) software engineering paradigm.

Comment: Yeah me too. Too much emphasis on inheritance as a cornerstone of OO I think. Looks great in the classroom with a very limited number of carefully chosen enhancements. Back in the real world where change is a given, in all but a few cases, turns your code base base into malformed alphabet soup. OO's version of spaghetti code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with abstract class, is which methods and properties are in it. 
If every descendant overrides every method in it, then it's a good design. Though you could just as easily used an interface instead. Abstract class is a better choice when you want to not just define the contract (method signatures), but also implement some default behaviours.

Think ToString(), if you don't override it, it returns the class name.

If you find yourself adding methods to the abstract class simply to override them in a small subset of descendants, then it's the wrong choice.

This is back to my instance is thingy or has a thingy.

My experience suggests abstract base class should only be used if the contract it defines is fixed by the requirements. If there's a lot of potential for change of what it does as opposed to how it does it, don't go near it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the inheritance per se, but that your template class looks like a [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) which is bad.

That's the reason it feels wrong to inherit from that class.

Comment: Even in a class that implements the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), the methods need to form a coherent unit. In your case it doesn't look like those methods have too much to do with each other.

Comment: So, would you consider the template of an ASP.NET page life cycle a God object? It knows Init/Load/Pre-render/Render etc. (+1 for God object, I'm new so this was very helpful to read about)

Comment: @DaveRook: I have to admit, I don't know that template. The methods look as if they belong together, so that would make it not a god object. On the other hand, a lot of the base classes in the .NET framework are quite bloated, so I wouldn't be too surprised if the template indeed would qualify as a god object.

Answer (score 1):

There are actualy some good points when to use and not to use inheritance.
You should read this article first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx(v=vs.80).aspx